# FFmpeg AVI to MP4 preserves sound, but not images

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, avi

Working with FFmpeg at a conversion (any file to MP4 (H.264/AAC)):

```
ffmpeg -y -i testdatei.avi -i logo.jpg -filter_complex overlay=15:15,scale=-1:720 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset medium -b:v 880k -g 10 -pass 1 -an -f mp4 -movflags faststart /dev/null
ffmpeg -y -i testdatei.avi -i logo.jpg -filter_complex overlay=15:15,scale=-1:720 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset medium -b:v 880k -g 10 -pass 2 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -movflags faststart xxx.mp4 2>&1
```

With MPEG and WMV file it's working. With two different AVIs it didn't work. Logfiles from path 1 aren't generated and output 1 is empty, output 2 of course generates an error.

After removing `-profile:v baseline` in both commands, the video file is successfully generated, but it's not possible to play it in JW Player (sound yes, but no image).

This is the result of the first command:

```
ffmpeg version git-2013-02-20-39b0393 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 20 2013 12:06:36 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libspeex --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      52. 17.102 / 52. 17.102
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.100 / 54. 63.100
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 38.103 /  3. 38.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[avi @ 0x23e4d80] non-interleaved AVI
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, avi, from 'testdatei.avi':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2013-02-21T14:06:32+01:00
    encoder         : Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 (Windows)
  Duration: 00:00:07.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 30330 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: dvvideo (dvsd / 0x64737664), yuv411p, 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Input #1, image2, from 'logo.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p, 170x82, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] using SAR=8/9
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.1, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] 264 - core 129 r2 bc13772 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=10 keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=10 rc=2pass mbtree=1 bitrate=880 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 cplxblur=20.0 qblur=0.5 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'xxx.mp4':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2013-02-21T14:06:32+01:00
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv444p, 1080x720 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, pass 2, 880 kb/s, 11988 tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (dvvideo) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (mjpeg) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
  scale (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le -> libfdk_aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   79 fps=0.0 q=30.0 size=     291kB time=00:00:02.58 bitrate= 922.4kbits/s   
frame=  162 fps=162 q=30.0 size=     620kB time=00:00:05.33 bitrate= 952.9kbits/s    
Starting second pass: moving header on top of the file"
frame=  227 fps=154 q=32766.0 Lsize=     958kB time=00:00:07.59 bitrate=1033.5kbits/s
video:829kB audio:120kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.986027%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] frame I:23    Avg QP:19.11  size: 31383
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] frame P:68    Avg QP:23.91  size:  1240
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] frame B:136   Avg QP:20.27  size:   310
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] consecutive B-frames: 19.8%  0.9%  0.0% 79.3%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] mb I  I16..4: 18.8% 68.4% 12.8%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] mb P  I16..4:  0.3%  0.3%  0.0%  P16..4: 10.7%  2.3%  0.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:85.6%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  9.1%  0.1%  0.0%  direct: 0.1%  skip:90.7%  L0:41.2% L1:58.6% BI: 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] 8x8 transform intra:68.3% inter:97.5%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] coded y,u,v intra: 53.7% 26.9% 30.8% inter: 0.5% 0.2% 0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] i16 v,h,dc,p: 70% 17%  1% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 25% 18%  4%  3%  4%  4%  6%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 33% 29%  8%  4%  6%  6%  5%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] ref P L0: 75.9%  5.1% 11.3%  7.7%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] ref B L0: 96.0%  3.1%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] ref B L1: 95.8%  4.2%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] kb/s:895.99
```

Output2:

```
ffmpeg version git-2013-02-20-39b0393 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 20 2013 12:06:36 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libspeex --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      52. 17.102 / 52. 17.102
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.100 / 54. 63.100
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 38.103 /  3. 38.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[avi @ 0x23e4d80] non-interleaved AVI
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, avi, from 'testdatei.avi':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2013-02-21T14:06:32+01:00
    encoder         : Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 (Windows)
  Duration: 00:00:07.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 30330 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: dvvideo (dvsd / 0x64737664), yuv411p, 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Input #1, image2, from 'logo.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p, 170x82, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] using SAR=8/9
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.1, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] 264 - core 129 r2 bc13772 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=10 keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=10 rc=2pass mbtree=1 bitrate=880 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 cplxblur=20.0 qblur=0.5 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'xxx.mp4':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2013-02-21T14:06:32+01:00
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv444p, 1080x720 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, pass 2, 880 kb/s, 11988 tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (dvvideo) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (mjpeg) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
  scale (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le -> libfdk_aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   79 fps=0.0 q=30.0 size=     291kB time=00:00:02.58 bitrate= 922.4kbits/s   
frame=  162 fps=162 q=30.0 size=     620kB time=00:00:05.33 bitrate= 952.9kbits/s    
Starting second pass: moving header on top of the file"
frame=  227 fps=154 q=32766.0 Lsize=     958kB time=00:00:07.59 bitrate=1033.5kbits/s
video:829kB audio:120kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.986027%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] frame I:23    Avg QP:19.11  size: 31383
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] frame P:68    Avg QP:23.91  size:  1240
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] frame B:136   Avg QP:20.27  size:   310
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] consecutive B-frames: 19.8%  0.9%  0.0% 79.3%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] mb I  I16..4: 18.8% 68.4% 12.8%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] mb P  I16..4:  0.3%  0.3%  0.0%  P16..4: 10.7%  2.3%  0.8%  0.0%  0.[0%    skip:85.6%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  9.1%  0.1%  0.0%  direct: 0.1%  skip:90.7%  L0:41.2% L1:58.6% BI: 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] 8x8 transform intra:68.3% inter:97.5%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] coded y,u,v intra: 53.7% 26.9% 30.8% inter: 0.5% 0.2% 0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] i16 v,h,dc,p: 70% 17%  1% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 25% 18%  4%  3%  4%  4%  6%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 33% 29%  8%  4%  6%  6%  5%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] ref P L0: 75.9%  5.1% 11.3%  7.7%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] ref B L0: 96.0%  3.1%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] ref B L1: 95.8%  4.2%
[libx264 @ 0x23e9640] kb/s:895.99
```

Do you have a idea why AVI makes problems? What could be the solution?

Comment: Are the console outputs actually from the above commands, or are they from when you omitted `-profile:v baseline`? Please use the actual names for the files and the actual console outputs for each displayed command. `ouput1` and `output2` are ambiguous terms.

Comment: These outputs are after removing -profile:v baseline! Here is the converted file, maybe you can find an answer in analyzing it http://www.file-upload.net/download-7238512/xxx.mp4.html

Comment: Please include the actual console outputs for your displayed commands.

Comment: The outputs u can see are the one of the top AFTER removing **-profile:v baseline**. Without removing there is no output.